# how can I use muti boost thread in a dll in background

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, boost, timer

The after part is my program, but it not work as what I expect. I want the Main window program call function "MyDllIniSys" in the dll, let the dll render window per maybe 32 microseconds till the Main window program set "bIAutoRender" not equal to 1.
So I wish the Function "MyDllIniSys" start the thread, and return at once.
But  but in what I did,the program wont work, cause if the thread start, it will never return.
How can I get it, someone pls. help.
Many thanks

```
static void renderOneFrame(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/,
    boost::asio::deadline_timer* t, int* iNeedAutoRender)
{


    //call Who use this DLL, let it refresh the window
    if(OnRefreshEvent)
    {
        OnRefreshEvent();
    }

    if(*iNeedAutoRender == 1)
    {
        t->expires_at(t->expires_at() + boost::posix_time::microseconds(iIRenderMicroSenconds));
        t->async_wait(boost::bind(renderOneFrame,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error, t, iNeedAutoRender));
    }

}

EXTERN_C MYDLLAPI INT MyDllIniSys(INT  WindowWidth,INT  WindowHeight)
{
    COgreRenderLoader myLoader;
    myLoader.IniOgre(externalWindowHandle,WindowWidth,WindowHeight);

    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::microseconds(iIRenderMicroSenconds));

    t.async_wait(boost::bind(renderOneFrame,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error, &t,&bIAutoRender));

    boost::thread thread1(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io));
    //io.run();
    thread1.join();
    //thread1.start_thread();

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling thread1.join() will block until thread1 finishes executing.  Leave it off, and your function will start the thread and return immediately.

The thread will continue, even though the thread1 object goes out of scope, [as you can see from this question](http://goo.gl/Q1C2a).